# Six single-digit numbers surrounding a three digit number - what's the rule?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Source: SOF World IMO Class 9

> Find the missing number, if the same rule is followed in all the three figures.
>
> ```
> 2 1 4    2 3 3    4 6 7
> \ | /    \ | /    \ | /
>  693      374       ?
> / | \    / | \    / | \
> 2 5 2    3 2 2    1 1 2
> ```
>
> - (A) 937
> - (B) 824
> - (C) 769
> - (D) 606

I have tried adding, multiplying, squaring, etc. but to no avail. What is the answer?

Answer (score 9):

I finally got it!

> Answer is (D) 606

Below is a detailed explanation

> First of all we can split central numbers in dividers: 693 = 3*3*7*11 and 374 = 2*11*17 
>  Then we can try to make any pair of dividers (for example 693 = 21*33) by using the 3 figures above, and the 3 figures below.. 
>  Finally, we can find that 2*2+1*1+4*4 = 21 and 2*2+5*5+2*2 = 33 
>  So, sum the squares of the 3 figures above, then sum the squares of the number below and multiply the 2 results to get the central number.
>  In other words, if A, B, C are the 3 top figures, and D, E, F are the 3 figures below, then the central number is 
>  (A^2+B^2+C^2) *  (D^2+E^2+F^2) 
>  
>  We can check that this rule works for 374: (2*2+3*3+3*3 = 22 and 3*3+2*2+2*2 = 17, and 374 = 22*17) 
>  
>  For the next one, we have 101 (4*4+6*6+7*7) and 6 (1*1+1*1+2*2) , so the answer is 101*6=606 (answer D)